HOW can DOMDocument::loadHTML() and ::saveHTML() fail?
According to the documentation, the DOMDocument::loadHTML() method "returns true on success or false on failure". My first question is how can it fail?
As well as correct HTML and very incorrect HTML, I have also tried feeding it complete, random, elbows-on-the-keyboard garbage with a few emojis added for good measure and it accepts it (adding the necessary tags to make an HTML document of it).
Likewise, the saveHTML method "returns the HTML, or false if an error occurred". So my second question is, under what circumstances can an error occur saving the HTML? The document exists because that's what the function is being called on, so how can outputting the HTML fail?
When I use the loadHTML and saveHTML methods, I assume I should check they have not returned false, but I don't understand when or why this could happen.

You'd have to look at the source code to see what it considers failure. The documentation is probably boilerplate, just in case error checks are added to the code.

The documentation doesn't always specify what are all possible failure conditions. It should but sometimes there are too many and sometimes the conditions are too exotic. Ideally, PHP functions should not return false on error. They should throw an error instead.
If you look at the PHP source code, you can see some examples of when loadHTML() would return false:

When $options is not an integer within PHP integer range.
When $source parameter is longer than PHP_INT_MAX.
When libxml returns a failure status. (You'd have to check with that library when it can fail.)


The documentation is general, and for php 7.x, 5.x the following code will truly return false:
var_dump(@(new DOMDocument())->loadHTML(""));

Example for php 8.x and 7.x (thanks to @Dharman's post)
var_dump(@(new DOMDocument())->loadHTML("Yo!", 1111111111111111));

But the interesting thing is that for PHP 5.6 this code will return true

I've just tried that exact code under PHP 8.1 and nothing is returned, because a ValueError is thrown: "Argument #1 ($source) must not be empty". Either way—returning false or throwing an error—this is worth knowing. If the ‘HTML’ comes from an external source, its being an empty string is a possibility which needs to catered for.

Yes, this difference was a revelation to me too, so thanks for the topic! I also updated the answer to include an example for php 8.  Here's a resource where you can look at the behavior for different versions -  https://onlinephp.io/c/36b9f
